# Is it possible to use text alignment with Braintree Hosted Forms?

Tags: css, braintree

I'm trying to use Braintree Hosted Forms to create a custom payment form for a client, however their design calls for centered text on the credit card number and expiration date fields.

I can't see text alignment on the list of styleable inner properties in Braintree's documentation, however this seems like something that should be fairly easy to do?

Does anybody know of any workarounds to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I'm a developer at Braintree. Be sure to reach out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com) at any time.</sub>

​
You are correct; the current release of Hosted Fields supports [a subset of CSS properties](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/styling/javascript/v2#inner-properties) based on a whitelist of known-safe CSS directives. This list can grow, and the best suggestion I have is to send a message to [Braintree Support](https://support.braintreepayments.com) and letting them know you are interested in this feature. 
​

The iframe solution is specifically designed to not allow hijacking of the DOM elements within the Hosted Fields iFrame so there isn't a a workaround to edit the HTML inside the iframe.
​